# Vibration sensor, using centripetal accelerometers

Tags: accelerometer

To measure (a) rpm and (b) whirling of a drive shaft, I have built a sensor with 3 centripetal accelerometers arranged at 120 degrees separation around the circumference of the housing. The maths indicates that rpm can be calculated from: Arpm = (A1 + A2 + A3)/3  and the whirl speed from the maximum value of: Awhirl = A1 + A2(cos120) + A3(cos240). The rpm calculation works perfectly for any shaft inclination between horizontal and vertical. However, the whirl calculation is only correct when the shaft is horizontal. I have had a second opinion on the maths and the whirl calculation should work at any inclination. So, I wonder if there is something that has been missed with regard to the accelerometers, which are Silicon Designs 1210J-005 (capacitative/analog) and respond to dc and ac accelerations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time visualizing your setup.  The RPM/centripetal acceleration calculation makes sense, but I can't see what you're trying to measure with the second equation.

Since you're using a 5g sensor, I'm guessing your rotational rate is slow enough that the acceleration due to gravity is going to be a significant error term in your calculations. The RPM equation will average this out, but the second will not (Although I'm not sure what it will do).  Another characteristic of your sensors is that they're limited to 400Hz signals - How fast is your shaft spinning?

Can you further explain what the maths you're using are supposed to be doing or how they were derived?

Comment: Insufficient space in "comments", so I have responded as an "answer". Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient space in "comments", so sent as an answer.

The shaft is rotating (to the right, say) along its longitudinal axis and remains undeflected until it reaches a critical speed (natural harmonic), at which the centre of the shaft deflects away from the original position of the longitudinal axis and orbits to the left, taking on the appearance of a standing wave. This form of lateral vibration is backward whirl, in which condition the accelerometers (located around the shaft circumference at the point of maximum deflection) experience simultaneously the centripetal force from the underlying forward rotation and the centripetal force from the backward orbit. The first equation averages out all external forces (including both whirl & gravity) and gives rpm. The second equation produces a periodic function, the recurring maximum value of which gives the speed of the backward whirl. Unfortunately the second equation only seems to work when the shaft is horizontal. Whether this is due to some assumption in the mathematical derivation or to misapplication of the accelerometers, I do not know. Shaft rotation speed is variable between 50 rpm and 250 rpm and backward whirl speed also lies between these rpm limits. The accelerometers are on a pitch circle radius of 94.15mm. The accelerometers are dc-coupled.

Comment: The standard method is to edit your question to include this additional information. If you do, you can then delete this answer (and this comment will disappear).  Don't have time ATM to look into this, but it looks like an interesting problem, and I'll give it a go tonight!

Comment: Okay. I follow the standard method in future. Hope you can help with the problem.